# Is there any plugin to add to every input of a form an autocomplete attribute

Tags: javascript

I recently found out that Google is keen about users autofilling their forms. So keen that with the last update its browser Chrome fires a warning if the autocomplete attribute is missing or wrongly coded:

> [DOM] Input elements should have autocomplete attributes (suggested: "current-password"): (More info: https://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/create-amazing-password-forms) `<input class=​"input-text" type=​"password" name=​"password" id=​"password">​`

I have searched around but i could only find how to "turn it off".

Since I find it very useful (agreeing with Google), I would like to know if there are libraries out there to automatically add the attributes accordingly.

so that:

```
<form>
 <input name="name" type="text" id="name">
</form>
```

becomes

```
<form>
 <input name="name" type="text" id="name" autocomplete="name">
</form>
```

taking the value from its 'name' attribute or 'id'.

More info on this: https://cloudfour.com/thinks/autofill-what-web-devs-should-know-but-dont/

Comment: You can easily do that with a little bit of JavaScript. Not really need a special plugin for that.

Comment: `autocomplete` has two values `on` and `off`.  Set autocomplete="off"

Comment: @MarkBaijens, libraries might be out there to assess issues described here: https://cloudfour.com/thinks/autofill-what-web-devs-should-know-but-dont/ . if you think my question is a good one, up vote it

Comment: @BendyZhang what part of: <<I have searched around but i could only find how to "turn it off">> did you not understand ??